# React - How to store global vars in a class (eg. User.username)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

So, I've created a little react app with a login, which is sending an ajax request to a local flask server, which returns `{token:TOKEN, user:{username:USERNAME,email:EMAIL}}` as `JSON`.

However, as my react app will have multiple pages, I'm using ReactRouter, but I can't figure out how to access variables such as `User.username` globally, in multiple `React.createClass({})` instances.

Bear in mind that I'm doing all of this client side (until I move to react server side rendering)

Currently, I'm storing these types of variables in `localStorage` but this means that they don't get automatically updated in the UI, without a url change, or a refresh.

```
const Admin = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Admin</h2>
        <p>Welcome, {localStorage.username}</p>
        {props.children}
    </div>
)
```

But what I would like to be able to do is

```
const Admin = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Admin</h2>
        <p>Welcome, {User.username}</p>
        {props.children}
    </div>
)
```

Routes

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>

            <Route path="login" component={Login}>
                <IndexRoute component={LoginForm}/>
                <Route path="twofactor" component={twoFactor}/>
                <Route path="backupcode" component={backupCode}/>
            </Route>

            <Route path="register" component={Register} onEnter={auth.auth_disallow}/>

            <Route path="admin" onEnter={auth.required} component={Admin}>
                <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
                    <IndexRoute component={DashboardIndex}/>
                </Route>

                <Route path="settings" component={Settings}>
                    <IndexRoute component={SettingsIndex}/>
                    <Route path="changepassword" component={ChangePassword}/>
                    <Route path="editinfo" component={EditInfo}/>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/logout" onEnter={auth.logout}/>
            </Route>

            <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>

        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: one ques, how on url change user info will change ? if once user is logged-in that info will be same through out the session, correct ?

Comment: Yes, unless they change their username, which they do have the ability to do

Comment: are you using any architecture like redux/flux or any store ? what is the main route inside u r rendering all other component ?

Comment: No, but I'm not opposed to the idea

Comment: can u show your main route ?  is it a stateful component ?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the ReactRouter

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple data that you need to share between components, you should go for a common store model i.e Redux or Flux.

So Instead of sharing data by storing in localStorage, you can store it in the Redux store and access it from there.

**[Here](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/02/redux.html)** is a nice tutorial on it

Comment: Are you able to add an example of this?

Comment: I have added a link to a nice getting started tutorial. If you face any issues, let me know I will edit the answer for the same

Comment: I'm still confused as to how the Redux store works, it seems overly complicated, and not really related to what I'm after

Comment: @Pipskweak Redux is complicated only at the initial step and if very useful when you want to share you states across components. If don't want to go for it you may well use react-cookie. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236025/dispatch-action-after-some-elapsed-period/41236250#41236250

Comment: This post ended up solving my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697268/member-variables-in-react-class-are-shared-by-reference

Comment: Can you elaborate on why he should be using redux or flux instead of localStorage or something simpler? There seems to be no reason to use more complicated storage options for something as simple as a username.

Unless there is a good reason I would advice op to just use local storage or something similar: https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react